# Ignore jquery call if nothing matched

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Hi I have a wired issue which I really dont know how can I explain to you guys. But I will try my best. Here is a jquery script I'm using on my site for calling different jquery functions or plugins like typed.js, flexislider etc etc.

```
(function ($) {
//Typed JS
    $(".element").typed({
        strings: ["Saumya Majumder.", "a geek.", "an Engineer.", "a Code Lover.", "a Google fan.", "an Apple fan.", "an Android fan.", "a WordPress fan.", "an Inventor.", "a Coffee lover.", "a Tea lover."],
        typeSpeed: 100,
        backDelay: 3000,
        loop: true
    });
    // Flixislider
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
    /* TOOLTIPS */
    $('.tooltip').each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).tooltipster({
            position: $(this).attr('data-tooltip-pos'),
            fixedWidth : 300,
            offsetX : 8,
            animation : "grow",
            delay : 50
        });

    });

    $('.bar').each(function() {
        var bar = $(this);
        bar.find('.progress').css('width', bar.attr('data-percent') + '%' );
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Now 1st I must tell that this is working fine with chrome and opera but creating issue on firefox.

**Here is the issue:**

In firefox when a user is visiting my page where I have the typed element to triger, but **no** flixislider to trigger and again a bar element to trigger. Whats happening is firefox 1st triggers the typed element as there is a call for that on the same page, and then it see that the page does not have any flexslider call, so it thwos and error and dont even read the below calls whether or not is there any more thing that might have used on that page.

But in chrome and opera, it just ignores the calls which are not present in that page. Sleek and exactly the thing I need.

Now suppose in a page where I dont have the typed element, it thwos error for the very 1st call and dont even check the rest. So none of my plugin calls will work.

**What I'm looking for**

As this is a firefox specific issue can anyone tell me how can I update my script code so that firefox just ignores the calls that are not ment for that page and execute the calls which are present on that page, like chrome, firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if there is any `.flexslider` before call the function :

```
if ($(".flexslider")[0]){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
}
```

Comment: there isn't. Say for example, in a single page I have `<div class="element">` which calls the typed function. but nothing else. On the other page I just have the fexslider call nothing else. Then this issue ouccour

Comment: yes, the _if_ thatI posted check programatically if there is at least one _flexslider_

Comment: I was thinking to break every single call into different `(function ($) { ... })(jQuery);` Will that be bad? in terms to loading?